# How can I make the input/text takes the whole width of the div in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, html, input, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use bootstrap 4, I have a simple div contains a text box. I want the text box to take the div width. I thought in Bootstrap the input, by default, take the full width?

What is really bugging me is that the code ran correctly here in the **snippet**??

Here is the sample code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md" style="background-color: blue;">
               <!-- this is the left side -->
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md" style="background-color: red;">
               <!-- this is the right side -->
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The above code is exactly what I have. I am not sure this is the right way to do this?

I don't know if this can help, I am using this code inside a view (MVC project).

So the this is how it looks inside visual studio:

Layout:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <div class="col-md d-none d-md-block">
           <!------>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My Project</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

And this is the view:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
```

This is how it looks when I render the view (there are other CSS related to background color, etc.. that I didn't add here)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Columns have padding of 15px on both sides. To remove the padding you can...

Use `p-0` for `padding:0` on the column with input:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md p-0" style="background-color: blue;">
               <!-- this is the left side -->
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md" style="background-color: red;">
               <!-- this is the right side -->
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Or, you can use `no-gutters` to remove padding from all cols in the `row`. This will also remove the negative margins from the row which will effect alignment with the sides of the viewport on smaller screens...

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md" style="background-color: blue;">
               <!-- this is the left side -->
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md" style="background-color: red;">
               <!-- this is the right side -->
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/d4AOm39YD3

Comment: Thank you, to explain more, I have edited my question and added a screenshot